# Selected value in dropdown list generated using MySQL query does not pass to variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a dropdown on my Wordpress page which uses a MySQL query to populate the values from MySQL to the dropdown list

This is the code on my Wordpress page

```
<form method="POST" action="">
[wpse_233034_shortcode]
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
[wpse_233036_shortcode]
</form>
```

The code used to generate the dynamic MySQL query is [wpse_233034_shortcode] which I have defined in the functions.php file

```
add_shortcode('wpse_233034_shortcode', function(){
global $wpdb;
$results1 = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT `Compound` FROM PNaphtha ORDER BY 
`SrNo`");
echo '<td><select id="Compound" name="Compound">';
echo '<option value="">Select Compound</option>';
foreach ( $results1 as $result1 ) {
echo '<option>'.$result1->Compound.'</option>';
}
echo '</select></td>';
});
```

It seems to be working fine until this point. When I dropdown the list, the value for the Compounds is selected from the PNaphtha table and populated on the screen.

What I want next is to pass the selected value from this dropdown into another shortcode/MySQL query which will fetch some more data associated with the Compound

This is what I have so far, however it does not seem to be be able to "pull" the value from the above dropdown into the next MySQL query

```
add_shortcode('wpse_233036_shortcode', function(){
global $wpdb;
$Compound = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Compound' );
$Compound = $Compound ? $Compound : 'acetone';
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM PNaphtha WHERE `Compound` = %s", 
$Compound );
$myrows1 = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
ob_start();
foreach ( $myrows1 as $row1) {
echo "Compound: ".$row1['Compound'].", "."Formula: ".$row1['Formula'].", 
"."Molecular Weight: ".$row1['MW']."<br>";
}
return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Now, the shortcode 'wpse_233036_shortcode' seems to be "working", as the default/static value specified 'acetone' is always queried and echoed on the page, even before I take a dropdown and select any value from the dropdown. This is what I get on page load

```
Compound: acetone, Formula: C3H6O, Molecular Weight: 58.08
```

[image]

What I want is for the dropdown to be populated using the first MySQL query as it does now

```
"SELECT `Compound` FROM PNaphtha ORDER BY `SrNo`"
```

Next, when I select a value from this dropdown, instead of the default 'acetone' the selected value should pass to

```
"SELECT * FROM PNaphtha WHERE `Compound` = %s", $Compound
```

I was able to get this to work using static/non-SQL queried dropdown list as shown below based on Sally's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299213/passing-value-from-a-dropdown-or-text-field-in-wordpress-to-mysql-query-in-funct)

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<select name="C_Option">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="abietic acid">abietic acid</option>
<option value="acenaphthene">acenaphthene</option>
...
<option value="acetone">acetone</option>
</select>
<input type="Submit">
[wpse_233032_shortcode]
</form>
```

Comment: What is `$Compound` between these two statements and after??? `$Compound = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Compound' );
$Compound = $Compound ? $Compound : 'acetone';`

Comment: $Compound = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Compound' ); Compound is also the <select id="Compound" name="Compound">. $Compound is supposed to be the selected value from the dropdown but I am not able to figure out how to get it there. Although it always defaults to 'acetone' and queries MySQL.

Comment: I was stating that you should `echo` it and verify what it actually is at different spots.

Comment: Thank you AbraCadaver, it returns a blank after the first and defaults to acetone after the second. If I change the default to something other than acetone, it queries the database for that compound and shows the formula and molecular weight. The problem seems to be with $Compound not getting the value from the dropdown.

Comment: On the first page load it will be blank and default to acetone.  You say it does this even after you submit the form?

Comment: It echoes the acetone formula and molecular weight on page load. When I select a compound from the dropdown it submits the form but does not update the acetone to the option I selected in the dropdown. Acetone and its properties continue to stay there on page load and on form submit. However, if I change the default acetone to say acenaphthene in functions.php, I start getting the properties associated with acenaphthene, on page load and submit.

Comment: @Quark, sorry about my previous comment (which I've removed) - I didn't notice the `select` name is `Compound`. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your shortcode callback/function (i.e. `wpse_233034_shortcode()`) is *not* returning any output, although it does `echo` the expected output.

Or more precisely, the `select` field in your `wpse_233034_shortcode()` function is outputted to the browser *before* the form HTML is outputted. Which means the form does *not* have the `select` field, hence when you submit the form, the key `Compound` is not available in the superglobal `$_POST`.

So make sure your shortcode is returning the proper output, but if you need to `echo` it in the shortcode callback, then use output buffering just as you did in the `wpse_233036_shortcode()` function.

```
add_shortcode('wpse_233034_shortcode', function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results1 = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT `Compound` FROM PNaphtha ORDER BY `SrNo`");

    ob_start(); // turn on output buffering
    echo '<td><select id="Compound" name="Compound">';
    echo '<option value="">Select Compound</option>';
    foreach ( $results1 as $result1 ) {
        echo '<option>'.$result1->Compound.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select></td>';

    return ob_get_clean(); // return the output
});
```

But where possible, avoid using output buffering and instead, assign the output to a variable, like so:

```
add_shortcode('wpse_233034_shortcode', function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results1 = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT `Compound` FROM PNaphtha ORDER BY `SrNo`");

    $output = ''; // save the output to this variable
    $output .= '<td><select id="Compound" name="Compound">';
    $output .= '<option value="">Select Compound</option>';
    foreach ( $results1 as $result1 ) {
        $output .= '<option>'.$result1->Compound.'</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select></td>';

    return $output; // return the output
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sally. I really appreciate your help. I will review your suggestion in a few hours and let you know in case I need more help.

Comment: Brilliant. Both the solutions work perfectly, I also read up about output buffering.

Comment: As always, I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ. I hope all is well. I am sorry to bother you again, I had a PHP question similar to this question, I was hoping if you could please take a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542349/echo-google-visualization-table-code-using-php) and advise.

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ. I was able to figure it out, I was missing a "," in my php code. I really appreciate all your help so far. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Quark. I'm glad you got it sorted, and you too have a nice day! :)